# Using for loop and 2d numpy array, is there a way to reduce the data even more?

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

The data represents a time-averaged connectivity pattern between EEG electrodes. The midline represents the value 0 because the connection to its own is marked as 0.

```
# plot the time-averaged connectivity
plt.imshow(time_average,cmap ='jet')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('channel')
plt.ylabel('channel')
```

[original time-averaged connectivity graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2iKw.png)

I am trying to extract the data represented only in the top triangle of the graph using for-loop.

```
time_average_data_red = [[0]*105 for i in range(105)]

for i in range (105):
    for ii in range(i):
        time_average_data_red[ii][i] = time_average[ii][i]
```

[reduced time-average-data graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhEDA.png)

Instead of making the repeating data value as 0 and plotting as above, is there a way to simply make the same graph without the lower bottom triangle of zero values?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [upper triangular matrix](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html#numpy.triu)

```py
import numpy as np
plt.imshow(np.triu(time_average, 1),cmap ='jet')
...
...
```

Comment: @MiriamHan don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem. So that it won't come again :)

Comment: How do you accept it as an answer? Sorry, I am new to stack overflow.